# Creating Form Validations in Bootstrap (without a plugin)

Tags: jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I don't necessarily need an entire jQuery plugin to handle the kind of validations I'm looking for here. Namely, I just want to keep one form input disabled until integers have been entered into two others, which will then unlock it. This is the if-loop I'm using to achieve this.

```
if ($("#q") && $("#target") === ''){
  $('#read_return_response_rate_ids').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
} else {
  $('#read_return_response_rate_ids').attr('disabled', '')
}
```

Bootstrap has this nifty markup selector called "disabled" where if you set it to "disabled", it'll actually disable the form input. I'm not sure if setting the disabled form field to an empty string will invert this, so that's also part of the problem here. I can't find anything pointing to the opposite of the disabled method on Google, so I'm unsure about whether there is an inverse to the "disabled" attribute.

Honestly, I feel like I'm missing something insignificant, and will be nuclear facepalming once the answer is revealed to me. Thanks in advance to those who do help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
$(document).keyup(function () {
    if ((isNaN($('#num1').val()) == false && $('#num1').val().length > 0) && (isNaN($('#num2').val()) == false && $('#num2').val().length > 0)) {
        $('#num3').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#num3').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xjs8p2ps/)

The 3rd textbox enables only when the first two textboxes contain numbers.

And just pointing out, the `disabled` attribute is an HTML5 attribute and not a Bootstrap specific attribute :)

Comment: FLAWLESS VICTORY /edit -- didn't know the disabled thing was an HTML5 attribute. Nice factoid!

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

`$('#read_return_response_rate_ids').removeAttr('disabled');`

and your code will look like
(update for regex `/^\d+$/.test(val)` to test if only numbers are entered):

```
function enableOrDisableField()
{
    if (/^\d+$/.test($("#q").val()) && /^\d+$/.test($("#target").val))
    {
         $('#read_return_response_rate_ids').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    else
    {
         $('#read_return_response_rate_ids').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}

$("#q").on("change",function(){
enableOrDisableField();
});
$("#target").on("change", function(){
enableOrDisableField();
});
```

Comment: This also worked, along with the above users answer, but I can't give the answer to them both. This is technically a more simple approach that solves the same problem, however I feel the above users' answer is more ironclad.

Still, great solution man. Thanks for the help